# Why is 0.0 not being counted?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Trying to make a list that puts the zeros onto the end. And it ignores the 0.0 which also need to be put on the end as a 0. Why is this happening?

Tried using `float(0)/ 0.0`. It works if I change it to a different integer just not 0.0.

Desired output `[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

```
def move_zeros(array):
    count = 0
    for x in array: #counts how many zeros
        if x is 0 or float(0):
            count+=1
    array = [x for x in array if x is not 0] # removes all zeros
    array = [x for x in array if x is not float(0)]
    for y in range(count):
        array.append(0) #tacks zero to the end of list

    print(array)

move_zeros([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9])
```

Expected to to work but it ignores `0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is will return True if two variables point to the same object, == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/10746224) excellent answer for a more detailed explanation of the difference between `is` and `==`.

As stated in other answers, you should use `==` and `!=` in your case, since you are checking if *values* are equal, rather than if the two objects are the same objects in memory.

Here is your code, with the errors fixed:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    count = 0
    result = []
    for x in array: #counts how many zeros
        if x == 0 or x == float(0):
            count+=1

        elif x is not False and x is not None:
            result.append(x)

    for y in range(count):
        result.append(0) #tacks zero to the end of list

    print(result)

move_zeros([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9])
```

Comment: There also may be False in the list sorry forgot to include that. That's why I used is rather than ==. But yes this answer was helpful. Thanks

Comment: @stumpedstump added an update to account for that.  Also I just realized that you really don't need the list comprehensions.  Instead you should check the conditions in your intial `for x in array` loop.  This way you only iterate once, instead of 3+ times.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `is` to perform arithmetic comparisons, and you can't combine two conditions using `or` like that. Change the condition as follows:

```
if x == 0:
```

Similarly fix conditions in your list comprehensions (`x != 0` instead of `x is not 0`).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

1. `is` evaluates if the two objects are the same object in memory. You want to use `==`.
2. `if x is 0 or float(0)` is not valid code. Use `if x is 0 or x == float(0)` or `if x in (0, float(0)` instead. You don't actually need to differentiate between `0` and `float(0)` though. Just use `if x == 0` or `if not x`.
3. This same problem is replicated in your list comprehensions. Use `x != 0` or simply `x` instead of `is not`.

Answer (score 0):

### A note about `or`:

- `x == 0 or x == float(0)` works
- `x in [0, float(0)]` also works and is simpler

  - `[x for x in array if x != 0]` & `[x for x in array if x != float(0)]` can be replaced with `[x for x in array if x not in [0, float(0)]]`

### Simplify the function

- [More on Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

  - `list.count()`
  - `list.extend()`

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    zc = array.count(0)
    array = [x for x in array if x != 0] # removes all zeros
    array.extend([0 for _ in range(zc)])

    return array

test = [9, 0.0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]

y = move_zeros(test)

print(y)

>>> [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

#### Verify `y` against `test`:

- [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
from collections import Counter

print(test.count(0))
>>> 10

print(y.count(0))
>>> 10

print(len(test))
>>> 20

print(len(y))
>>> 20

test_dict = Counter(test)
print(test_dict)
>>> Counter({9: 4, 0.0: 10, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 1})

y_dict = Counter(test)
print(y_dict)
>>> Counter({9: 4, 0.0: 10, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

#### Alternatively:

- Use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```py
test = [9, 0.0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]

test_sorted = test.sort(reverse=True)
print(test_sorted)
>>> [9, 9, 9, 9, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```